# Android Studio 20% CPU usage when idle

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I noticed my Android studio 3.5.1 on Windows 10 permanently consumes 20 - 30 % of CPU even though I haven't touched it for 2 days (I didn't turn off my computer for more than 2 days). There is a project open in Android Studio. Is there anything I can turn off to force Android Studio not to consume any CPU when I'm not using it?

Comment: that's not normal behavior.  A build may have frozen.

Comment: you are probably right, after Android Studio restart the CPU usage is 0 %

Comment: I have the exact same problem and as of now I haven't found any solutions yet ...

Comment: <<I couldn't find solution>> I have the same problem. And in addition to high cpu usage, when it happens also there is another problem which is not showing errors on files. When I run project it shows error on build panel but not in files. Also today I discover another problem. For now android studio works normal with 0-1 percent when idling but when I add one particular library to gradle and sync, android studio turns crazy and use 30+ cpu and not shows error in files. Very interenting error, and even more interesting is very few people encounter this error.

Answer (score 0):

what do you see if you open up the item that is getting the most use?
Click on the little arrow to the left of it to expand the thread and see what it is

If you have services using the service local host process and taking up lot of resources, sometimes disabling services in services.msc can help. High service host usage is a common problem in Windows 10 especially on less powerful processors. I would start by disabling internet connection sharing if you aren't using it.

If Windows Update is known for causing problems. It's really the only core thing on your system that changes modifies it unless you change the hardware. It could be fixed by a future update but I wouldn't hold my breath.

The internet saying not to mess with system processes is correct because Windows needs them. Services are different from system processes though. Services can be disabled and often are. If I don't need "offline files" for example, I can disable that service and only that service stops. Your problem is that "Internet connection sharing" and a couple other services that are related to Windows firewall are using the svchost system process heavily and taking up resources.

I would start by disabling the internet connection sharing service if you don't need it. It's a service that allows your PC to share its internet connection with others. Base filtering Engine and Firewall should be left alone though. If those 2 are still causing issues one workaround is to install a 3rd party irewall like Comodo or Norton and disable Windows Firewalll and not use it at all.